# Is the words "of his own" necessary here?

Tags: grammar

In *Memento* (2000), Leonard says to Natalie, who got beaten by Dodd:

> Leonard: I'll go see him.
>
> Natalie: And?
>
> Leonard: I'll give him some bruises **of his own** and tell him to look for
> a guy called Teddy.

Is the words "of his own" necessary here?

Comment: Presumably Dodd has given Natalie bruises, so Leonard intends to give _him_ some in return.

Comment: That phrase emphasizes that the bruises will be Dodd's, to distinguish them from Natalie's. It isn't strictly necessary but helps to maintain the distinction.